# Special character fails installation of Oracle Weblogic Server 12x

Tags: oracle, windows-10, weblogic

I'm trying to install "Oracle WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4" on Windows 10 with
`java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls_quick.jar` command run on Git Bash. Problem is my folder account name (let's say UserŃame) has special characters and I cannot change that. This is error message that I've got:

```
The directory path "C:\Users\User▒ame\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-01-05_04-13-52PM" contains invalid characters.
Unable to locate or create a temporary directory for the Oracle Universal Installer.
```

Are there any tricks to bypass this extraction to temp folder maybe?

I'm trying setup new local account with admin privileges but after creation I cannot log in to it... this is different problem.

Comment: You can try to set a different temp dir with this JVM property -Djava.io.tmpdir

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set a different temp dir with this JVM property -Djava.io.tmpdir